# Authenticate two different users from different models using nodejs/express/mongoose/jwt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, jwt

I am developing a MERN app where students can log into fill out their applications, and admin users (with different roles) who can approve applications and do other admin stuff. So, I decided to have two different models(mongoDB collections) for the users (student & users) as students have additional data that is needed to be stored in the DB. What would be the best approach for authentication? and what's the best way to structure the routes?

Answer (score 0):

it'll be much easier to handle only one model (users) and just to add a role field.
so you'll have to query only one collection in order to find the user in the login process.
if you're using Express with JWT you have to write some middleware to handle the token and pass the request to the handler or abort it with 401, you simply add some if statement to check if the role in the payload of the token is a student or admin

Comment: In the app, students have fill out a form(application). if so, should I add those data into the User schema or would it be better to create another collection like student or application to store those data. and how what would be my API structure?

Comment: mongo allows you to use both, subdocuments and "normalization" similar to SQL. I would go with the second option, e.e another collection

Answer (score 0):

First given your scenario, it's simple, when they try to login ask them using some checkbox or some mechanism they want to login as user or login as student, and then run your login logic based on that.

However it would really make sense if you just have one model for authentication such as users and then have a field `user_role` to control their privileges/authorisation.

For Routes, you can have middleware to check, based on user_role they can access it or not.